# In WordPress, using Formidable Forms, how do you identify individual combined fields under one field name?

Tags: wordpress, forms

**Situation:**
In WordPress, using Formidable Forms, I have source form that contains a Name field with ID 1940 in a field layout of First/Last which produces two text fields (i.e. first name and last name).  Upon submission of the source form, it is being redirect to a target form which the source field values are copied to.  The mechanism I am using is https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/automatically-populate-fields/.

**Specific Problem:**
For the target form, when I use [frm-field-value field_id=1940 entry=pass_entry] for the default values of first and last name fields, it copies over the concatenated strings of first name and last name into each field.

**Desired Result:**
I want the source form first name copied to the target form first name field, and source form last name copied to the target form last name field.  I tried for the field ids: (1) 1940-first, 1940-last AND (2) 1940|first, 1940|last; but to no avail.  Any ideas?